# Unable to upgrade to 22.04 from 21.10 due to missing i386 packages

Tags: upgrade, updates, 21.10, do-release-upgrade, 22.04

When trying to upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04, I'm getting error that some i386 packages are not found:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/ocl-icd/ocl-icd-libopencl1_2.2.14-3_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sndio/libsndio7.0_1.8.1-1.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openal-soft/libopenal1_1.19.1-2build3_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ncurses/libncurses5_6.3-2_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ncurses/libtinfo5_6.3-2_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libv/libva/libva2_2.14.0-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/intel-gmmlib/libigdgmm12_22.1.2%2bds1-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/intel-media-driver/intel-media-va-driver_22.3.1%2bdfsg1-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libroken18-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libasn1-8-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libheimbase1-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libhcrypto4-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libwind0-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libhx509-5-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libkrb5-26-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libheimntlm0-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/heimdal/libgssapi3-heimdal_7.7.0%2bdfsg-3ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/llvm-toolchain-12/libllvm12_12.0.1-19ubuntu3_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mesa/mesa-va-drivers_22.0.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/intel-vaapi-driver/i965-va-driver_2.4.1%2bdfsg1-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libv/libva/va-driver-all_2.14.0-1_i386.deb 404  Not Found
```

Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT: The output of `sudo apt update` command is:

```
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                                               
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease                                                                                                                       
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                             
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                                                                            
Hit:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                                                                      
Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                                       
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyzardking/ubuntu-make/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt impish-pgdg InRelease                                                                                                                  
Hit:14 https://paulcarroty.gitlab.io/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/debs vscodium InRelease                                                                 
Hit:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                                    
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu impish InRelease 
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rvm/smplayer/ubuntu impish InRelease                                       
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [115 kB]                               
Hit:18 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 Packages [384 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [25.7 kB]                                                                                        
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe i386 Packages [122 kB]                                                                                             
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 Packages [194 kB]                                                                                            
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [35.6 kB]                                                                                    
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]                                                                                    
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [16.4 kB]                                                                                  
Fetched 1,104 kB in 15s (72.2 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

`sudo apt upgrade` output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I would suggest a clean reinstall: spring cleanup. Note that 32 bit is not anymore supported, so if this is a 32 bit system, you cannot upgrade.

Comment: @vanadium. it's not a 32 bit system, it's 64 bit with some 32bit packages installed. And I don't really want to do a clean reinstall. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo apt update`. Make sure to format the pasted output with the {} icon.

Comment: @heynnema I did it

Comment: Looks good. Now do `sudo apt upgrade` and show me the output.

Comment: @heynnema done.

Comment: How were you trying to upgrade... Software Updater?

Comment: @heynnema, yes.

Comment: Try again. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema, why should I try again? nothing changed.

Comment: Because the problem may have been on the other end... and because I asked you to :-)

Comment: @heynnema, tried again. still failing for the same reason.

Comment: Two next steps... open `Software & Updates`, **Other Software** tab, and uncheck all items. Try `Software Updater` again. If that still doesn't work, go back to `Software & Updates`, **Ubuntu Software** tab, and uncheck UNIVERSE, then try `Software Updater` again. Report back. I've got to leave for an hour or so... I'll check in when I return.

Comment: Problem solved by choosing different mirror. The mirror I used didn't support i386 package

Comment: What mirror did you change from and to?

Comment: Please consider accepting my quickie answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the comments...

Problem solved by choosing different download mirror in `Software & Updates`.